# Why some visitors cannot see my website properly?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server

I bought my domain name (http://www.geekroo.com.au) from GoDaddy and set up my website on Linode VPS(using Linode DNS). I know little about website stuffs so I just simple followed the guides on linode.com to install Nginx plus other softwares.

I always get some reports from visitors, they say they can only see the default page of Nginx, not the proper website. Some other reports just simple say the website is "broken".

It really makes me confused as the website is working for most visitors. Can someone please give me some tips or clues?

Thanks very much!

Karl

Comment: The first tip is to get a proper problem report from your user: exact date/time (inc. timezone), exactly what they did (URLs visited, links clicked), and what they saw (a screenshot is extra-helpful).  Then you can correlate that with what you see in your logs.

Comment: If it's a new buy, you can wait to have all DNS's spread correctly, as we don't know if the visitor didn't landed somewhere else in such case, but you need good user report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a `listen` directive in your nginx `server` block.

Right now it looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    #...everything else
```

You need to add a line:

```
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
```

The reason for this is that you have both IPv4 and IPv6, but you have only configured your virtual host to answer on IPv4. Thus, anyone who has IPv6 (like me) gets the default nginx page (which *is* set to answer on IPv6).

Comment: The line `listen [::]:80;` was surely missing in my config file. I added it. I guess it should be able to fix the issue.

Comment: @Karl Yes, it seems to work on IPv6 now. I see a bunch of Raspberry Pi projects, instead of the nginx default page.